# Get the shortest path from certain node to ANY node of a given label in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I have a node, let's call it X. I wanna find the closest node to X, let's name it Y and Y has to have a certain label. If there are multiple such Y nodes at the same distance to X, I'd like them all to be returned

Suppose we have nodes A and B of a certain label. The minimum path length from X to A is 3 and from X to B is 5. I want it to return A and only A. If the minimum path length is equal, I'd like it to return both of them (both A and B)

Here's what I have so far :

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((selectedNode {name:'X'})-[*]-(y:GivenLabel))
WITH y.name as y, length(p)=min(length(p)) AS l
RETURN y
```

The problem of this query is that it returns both A and B in the above example, no matter what the minimum path to each one of them is. I thought about using LIMIT 1 and ordering them but then it'll only display one of them, even if the minimum path length to each one of them is equal

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [collect](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) function will let you return a single row containing a list of values.

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((selectedNode {name:'X'})-[*]-(y:GivenLabel))
RETURN length(p) AS l, collect(y.name) as targets
ORDER BY l
LIMIT 1
```

If you want to return the values as individual records, instead of a list, you can use [UWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/).

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((selectedNode {name:'X'})-[*]-(y:GivenLabel))
WITH length(p) AS l, collect(y.name) as targets
ORDER BY l
LIMIT 1
UNWIND targets as target
RETURN l, target
```

Comment: Could it be updated so the 1,2 or more values returned are returned as separate entities aka the standard way Neo4J returns things, without using an array?

Comment: UNWIND is the opposite of collect. It breaks a list down into separate rows. I'll edit the original response to show how that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have APOC Procedures, you can use one of the path expander procs to find a shortest path to a given label and limit it. Unfortunately you'll need a second call to get multiple nodes of the label at the same distance away.

```
// assume we've already MATCHed to selectedNode
...
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(selectedNode, {labelFilter:'/GivenLabel', limit:1}) YIELD path
WITH selectedNode, length(path) as pathLength
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(selectedNode, {labelFilter:'/GivenLabel', maxLevel:pathLength}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

In the label filter, the prefix of `/` indicates that the label will be used in a termination filter, once it finds the first occurrence it will stop expanding, and use the node as a result.

The path expander procs use breadth-first expansion by default, so it will be the shortest path from your starting node to a node of the given label.

`limit:1` ensures that we return after finding the first result (this can be very expensive if there is no such node of the given label, or if it's far away, so you might consider providing a `maxLevel` as an upper bound).

We make a similar path expander call (subgraphNodes(), since we no longer need the path, just the node at the end) using the length of the path found previously as our maxLevel, that will return all nodes with the given label at that distance.